# Exporting images with their layer's effect (Dim) still active

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, export, layer-style

For a project of mine, I have one layer with an image and I had the layer option for Dim active on it. However, when I export it, the Dim effect is not present on the resultant product.

Is there any way to retain that dim effect through the export?

Comment: Are you referring to the "Dim Images" option for a layer? All that does it reduce the opacity of the layer.

Comment: Instead of using the Dim Images feature, select the image, and lower its opacity in the Appearance panel instead.